# Google Maps Javascript polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In google maps v2 there is a function for polygons enableDraw() has this been disabled in version 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope these links help you:

[google maps API v3 - how to draw dynamic polygons/polylines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394961/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-draw-dynamic-polygons-polylines)

[Polygon Drawing and Getting Coordinates with Google Map API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072059/polygon-drawing-and-getting-coordinates-with-google-map-api-v3)

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons

Comment: Thanks, There is a good link in the second link with some good examples I've not seen before.