# Google Maps api - drawing library fill polygon before closing shape

Tags: google-maps-api-3, drawing, polygons

I have a google map and I am using the drawing library to let the user draw polygons on the map by clicking to add points.
As a comparison I looked at trulia.com. I don't know how the drawing library setup is being made on trulia (uses backbone and other stuff). While I draw a shape, I want it to get filled as soon as I have 3 points, even if I am still drawing, and the fill should change as I add new points (indicating what the shape/area would be if you'd close it in that moment).

On trulia.com, as soon as you have a 3rd point, the area designated by the existing points gets filled, even though you haven't finished adding points. They're using google maps api, right? But I can't find the setting for something like "fill shape as you add points". I've searched google a lot, no luck.

Does anyone know how to setup the map or the drawing library to have that behavior? I don't think that this behavior can be setup in the polygonOptions (I've looked at all the options documented on developers.google.com)... so, the setting must be somewhere else...

Comment: Off the cuff (and on my mobile), you'll probably need to use your mouse position (in LatLng) as the penultimate point from verticeCount=2 and up. I suspect the hard part will be "encouraging"  the renderer to cleanup/redraw as the mouse moves.

Comment: so there is no option for this offered by google... sadly.

thanks for answering

Comment: Have you tried setting the `fillColor = #00FFFF;` and `fillOpacity = 0.8;` values for the polygonOptions?

Comment: @elrobis this has nothing to do with my question :) of course I already have a fillColor and fillOpacity set up, but the values from those options are only used when I've finished drawing and closed the shape. What I needed was for the shape to be filled as I am drawing and adding points, to get filled while adding each new point as if it were the closing point (but not actually close the shape untill I click on the initial point again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MrCroft, it seems @ddtpoison777 asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394961/google-maps-api-v3-how-to-draw-dynamic-polygons-polylines?rq=1) and found [the solution](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/poly_edit.html) among some Google Maps API samples. This is the relevant code taken from the example:

```
var poly;
var path = new google.maps.MVCArray;

function initialize() {
    poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#5555FF'
    });

    poly.setMap(map);
    poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([path]));

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPoint);
}

function addPoint(event) {
    path.insertAt(path.length, event.latLng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng,
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });
    markers.push(marker);
    marker.setTitle("#" + path.length);
}
```

Comment: I gave up on this... stopped searching and moved on because I could (wasn't mandatory). I was actually looking to make sure if there is a drawing setting that would simply accomplish this, not do it myself :) It would have been natural for such a setting/drawing mode to exist. It's a visual aid... Shame on google.

But, since I haven't explicitly stated that in my question, I have to accept your answer :P

Thank you!

Comment: ...that's just it, though, the API does seem to naturally support the behavior you want, which the code above accomplishes. If you just follow [the link](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/poly_edit.html) and create three points, you'll see that. I suspect the trick is putting your points into their `MVCArray` object and assigning that object to the Polygon through its `setPaths()` method..

Comment: unfortunately it acts like a closed shape... because that's what it is I think. You can not put a point "inside" it, like you would if it wasn't closed. Let's say we have 3 points, you should be able to seet a 4th "inside" the triangle and the triangle shape would still change in a quadrilateral. So, I would have had to dive into more than the above code. Anyway, luckily I don't have to investigate anymore as I've moved past it... the initial desired behavior was like when you click "Draw Your Search" on trulia.com. I am not interested in doing that anymore.